# SELECT Oracle syntax for getting duplicate records using EXISTS and IN directives

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

I'm struggling with a SQL query, it should be based on a table structure like this:

```
PID (type VARCHAR)    ATTR (type VARCHAR)
U1                    attribute1
U1                    locale
U2                    attribute1
U2                    locale
U3                    attribute1
U3                    attribute2
```

What I would like to do is to select all `PID`s not having a record containing the string 'locale' in the ATTR column, so in the example I have shown, this query should return 'U3'

I have tried queries like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID p
FROM tablename
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table
                  WHERE PID = 'p' AND ATTR NOT IN 'locale');
```

and similar stuff, but I either haven't understood the SQL syntax properly or am making some other mistakes - I'm not getting the correct results.

Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

P.S. Guys, due feedback I got, I must do something wrong, let me please complete some information, maybe it will help.

The table Im talking about is a SAP J2EE stack standard table (UME_STRINGS), containing user data (UME in SAP terms - user management engine). It contains many other fields beside PID and ATTR, I didn't consider those, since it seems they doesn't matter.

However, I need to find all user accounts without a set locale. Since the user management is working "lazy" obviously, such a record (record with an arbitrary PID and value 'locale' in ATTR) will only be created as soon you are setting the locale. This means in fact there are many arbitrary records for the user in the table (same PID value), but none of those have a value 'locale' in the ATTR field. So the algo could be:

1.)cluster the table on identical PID's

2.)iterate over the cluster and check inside of every cluster, if there is no record with 'locale' in ATTR field within this cluster, add this PID to output

3.)return the list with found PID's

All this would be done ideally with a single SQL query.

Available JAVA API (com.sap.security.api.IUserSearchFilter) doesn't allows you to set null values for searching, so I have no choise but to ask DB directly.

Besides of 'locale' records are of course many others, because every attribute for a user, group, role etc is modelled in this manner - stuff like U1 - attribute1 etc.

So what I need is query giving me PID's for user, who haven't an entry like "PID - 'locale' in ATTR.

If my description is confusing or incomplete, please ask. Thanks again

P.P.S. added some screenshots with sample data and table structure

[image: table structure]

[image: sample data]

[image: could PID be null?]

Comment: Can PID be null? (You can check in your actual data: `select count(PID) where PID is null`).

Comment: No, due ER it has always a value set

Answer (score 3):

No need for `EXISTS()` or `IN()` , you can simply use the `HAVING` clause with a `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.pid
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.pid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.attr = 'locale' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, sounds right, but in fact delivers too much data, also U1 and U2. In fact only U3 should come. Maybe Im doing something wrong or forgot to mention something?

Comment: @JohnDoe - This answer is correct (and a few of the other answers were correct too) so you must be doing something wrong. Please share some data where you feel this query produces the wrong result.

Comment: I have the same feeling mathguy, I represented only an extract of the problem, to keep the things simple. Doesn't seems it was a good idea, I edited my entire post and added some information, maybe it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a not IN and sub select

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID 
FROM tablename
WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM table
                      WHERE  ATTR =  'locale');
```

eventually try `TRIM(BOTH  FROM ATTR)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID 
FROM tablename
WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM table
                      WHERE LOWER(TRIM(BOTH  FROM ATTR))=  'locale');
```

Comment: thank you, but wrong syntax, cant work at all. Im on 11g, maybe it matters

Comment: sorry scaisEdge, delivers "no rows selected"

Comment: This may fail if there is a row with PID (null) and attr = 'locale' - but in that case it will return no answers, not "too many" answers.

Comment: @mathguy   correct ..  my answer  is only related  to the data sample provided  by OP

Comment: PID cant be null and the changed query delivers too much data. It seems it includes also U1 and U2 data, Im assuming anything excepting U1 - locale, U2 - locale etc. I need rather single PID values, which does not have records in the same table like PID - locale

Comment: @JohnDoe  the query don't should return  value for PID where ATTR is = locale  .. check for data .. sample

Comment: @JohnDoe - the only thing I can think of is that `'locale'` in your data may contain spaces you can't see, or may be in different capitalization (`'locale'` is not the same thing as `'Locale'` or `'LOCALE'`!)

Comment: Hm, it obviously also returns records with PID's with ATTR <> 'locale', even for PID's which have such an 'locale' entry, I dont want this. This could be the problem?

Comment: Thank you mathguy, I throw a select for 'LOCALE' - there are no such records

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID
FROM tableName
WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM tableName WHERE Attr = 'locale')
```

Comment: Thank you, but delivers too much data, analogous to sagi's answer. Im expecting to became only values, which does not have records with arbitrary PID and 'locale' value in ATTR. In my example this would be U3

Comment: above query returns U3 only becuase U2 and U1 have rows with Attr value as locale

Comment: not if I run the query on my machine (Oracle 11g, Win 2008 R2 server), thank you anyway. I have the feeling my scenario isn't complete, I added some information in my entire post, please feel free to ask if you missing something

Comment: @JohnDoe Please edit your post again and add the query you are running now and doesn't work.

Comment: sagi, this is simple - none of the suggested queries has worked for me :) Im assuming its a layer 8 problem, but I cant figure our what Im doing wrong. I have completed the entire problem description, it is quite straight and exactly now imho, if you are missing something - let me know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PID p
FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename t2
                  WHERE t2.PID = t.PID AND t2.ATTR = 'locale');
```

Comment: Thank you, but delivers "no rows selected"

Comment: that should have been `... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename t2
                  WHERE t2.PID = t.PID AND t2.ATTR = 'locale');`

Comment: thank you, but similar to other answers it delivers too much data - obviously also records like U1 - attribute1, we don't want do that

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Problem n some of other queries is that the not exists looks only for the attr locale, withoud joinig by PID.

```
select t1.pid from tablename t1
where not exists 
(select t2.pid from tablename t2 where t2.pid=t1.pid and    t2.attr='locale');
```